# How to find the table having number of procedures , functions, view, indexex, triggers in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose emp table having views, functions, procedures, triggers. So how can i find table having these object_type.please explain me

Answer (score 2):

You can use the USER_DEPENDENCIES or ALL_DEPENDENCIES view provided by Oracle. Please refer to the following links.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1041.htm#i1576452

http://www.oratable.com/which-objects-refer-to-this-table/

In your case you can fire the following query.

```
SELECT * from ALL_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE'
AND REFERENCED_NAME = 'EMP'
```

Comment: Thank you so much give valueable  solution

Answer (score 1):

Oracle also provides tools called utldtree. To install it you have to execute. `utldtree.sql` from `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin`.

Script creates a few object tables ideptree, deptree and procedure deptree_fill.

```
exec deptree_fill('TABLE',user,'YOUR_TABLE');
  select * from  deptree;
  select * from ideptree;
```